# facebook app add in timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

i made a facebook app,
although it is working ( i think ) but it does not look like normal facebook apps!

the first app page does not appear in my case!

this page :
http://pollsdb.com/app1.png

beside when i open the app it does not show in my timeline that i accessed or opened this app

how to do that the welcome page and to show in users timeline??
this is my app
http://apps.facebook.com/asmgxtestone/?fb_source=search&ref=ts&qtnid=12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the first app page does not appear in my case!

That’s not “the first page” of an app, that’s the **OAuth dialog**.

You can enable *authenticated referrals* in your app’s settings, then users will get prompted to connect to your app when they click on certain links to your app in facebook (f.e. feed stories).

To authenticate/connect users coming from different places, you have to do the OAuth stuff yourself - please see documentation, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

> beside when i open the app it does not show in my timeline that i accessed or opened this app

Since you haven’t implemented OAuth yet, there is nothing to show, since you can’t actually connect to your app.

And once you have that enabled (plus set *social discovery* to enabled in your app’s settings), feed stories will not show up immediately – it needs a certain distribution and user base for these stories to start appearing.

> this is my app

Link doesn’t work, just gives an error saying the app developer messed something up.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, it was really helpful. i managed to get the authentication dialog :)  now users can give me permission...   the problem is that my app does not post anything on user's timeline. i noticed other apps like socialcam "Post on your behalf" option but could not find it in my app! could this be the reason? help appreciated